# Jest 29 with ts-test in React 17 Typescript gives Typescript errors on specific node_module package

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, ts-jest

When running all test suites within my project, only 1 test suite fails with the following TS validation error.

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    node_modules/@myorg/apple/src/components/apple-application/AppleApplication.tsx:637:8 - error TS2322: Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.

    637        {node}
               ~~~~~~

      node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:1343:9
        1343         children?: ReactNode | undefined;
                     ~~~~~~~~
        The expected type comes from property 'children' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>, HTMLAnchorElement>'
```

The jest.config.js is

```
module.exports = {
    testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
    testTimeout: 25000,
    maxConcurrency: 20,
    collectCoverageFrom: [
        'src/**/*.js',
        'src/**/*.ts',
        'src/**/*.tsx',
        '!**/index.*',
        '!**/components.*',
        '!**/node_modules/**',
        '!**/*.stories.*',
        '!**/*.md',
        '!src/helpers/file.js',
        '!src/helpers/jest-setup.js',
    ],
    reporters: ['jest-progress-bar-reporter'],
    coverageReporters: ['lcov', 'text-summary'],
    testMatch: ['**/?(*.)spec.[tj]s?(x)'],
    testEnvironmentOptions: { url: 'http://localhost' },
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['raf/polyfill', '<rootDir>/src/helpers/jest-setup.ts'],
    transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/((?!(@myorg))/)'],
    transform: {
        'src/.+\\.(j|t)sx?$': 'ts-jest',
        'node_modules/(@myorg)/.+\\.(j|t)sx?$': 'ts-jest',
    },
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga|md)$':
            '<rootDir>/src/mocks/file.js',
        '^.+\\.(css|less|scss|md)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
    },
    coverageThreshold: {
        global: {
            lines: 90,
            statements: 90,
        },
    },
};
```

Also disabling diagnostic for this specific module does not resolve the issue.

```
transform: {
        'node_modules/(@myorg)/apple/.+\\.(j|t)sx?$': [
            'ts-jest',
            {
                diagnostics: false,
            },
        ],
        'src/.+\\.(j|t)sx?$': 'ts-jest',
        'node_modules/(@myorg)/.+\\.(j|t)sx?$': 'ts-jest',
},
```

package.json

```
{
    "config": {
        "commitizen": {
            "path": "./node_modules/cz-conventional-changelog"
        }
    },
    "resolutions": {
        "babel-eslint-parser/semver": "^7.3.2"
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "private": true,
    "license": "ISC",
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://gitlab......"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "build": "webpack --mode=production",
        "build:analyse": "webpack --mode=production --env=analyse=true",
        "build:ota": "webpack --mode=development",
        "build:ota:analyse": "webpack --mode=development --env=analyse=true",
        "build:storybook": "build-storybook -c .storybook -o storybook-static",
        "commitizen": "git-cz",
        "lint:js": "eslint --fix --ext .ts,.tsx src",
        "lint:less": "stylelint --syntax less",
        "prepare": "husky install",
        "prettier": "prettier --write --check 'src/**/*.{ts,tsx,css,json,md}'",
        "sonar": "sonar-scanner -Dproject.settings=sonar-project.properties",
        "start": "start-storybook -p 9001 -c .storybook",
        "test": "NODE_ENV=test && jest --silent --maxWorkers=50%",
        "test:coverage": "jest --coverage --ci --silent --maxWorkers=50%",
        "test:debug": "NODE_ENV=test && jest -t 'debug*' --maxWorkers=50%",
        "test:regression": "yarn run test -c jest.config.regression.js --maxWorkers=50%",
        "test:watch": "yarn run test --watch --maxWorkers=25%"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@myorg/account-helpers": "^2.6.0",
        "@myorg/api": "^5.0.7",
        "@myorg/application": "^12.0.0",
        "@myorg/browser": "^4.2.0",
        "@myorg/card": "^19.3.3",
        "@myorg/core-less-imports": "^2.2.18",
        "@myorg/description-list": "^11.0.0",
        "@myorg/design-tokens": "^10.2.0",
        "@myorg/form": "^21.1.2",
        "@myorg/form-block": "^9.4.0",
        "@myorg/form-block-address": "^15.2.1",
        "@myorg/form-block-password-create": "^14.1.0",
        "@myorg/form-field-birthday": "^12.1.1",
        "@myorg/form-field-checkbox": "^9.1.0",
        "@myorg/form-field-datepicker": "^16.7.5",
        "@myorg/form-field-iban": "^10.1.1",
        "@myorg/form-field-input": "^10.1.0",
        "@myorg/form-field-input-radio-button-group": "^14.0.1",
        "@myorg/form-field-nationality": "^10.0.0",
        "@myorg/form-field-select": "^10.1.0",
        "@myorg/form-field-telephone": "^10.1.0",
        "@myorg/form-field-username": "^10.1.0",
        "@myorg/form-footer": "^9.2.0",
        "@myorg/grid": "^2.1.3",
        "@myorg/inpage-navigation": "^7.1.0",
        "@myorg/apple": "^4.1.2",
        "@myorg/modal": "^20.0.0",
        "@myorg/monitoring": "^2.1.0",
        "@myorg/my-page": "^5.5.0",
        "@myorg/notification": "^15.1.1",
        "@myorg/panel": "^30.1.0",
        "@myorg/providers-application": "^2.1.0",
        "@myorg/theme": "^10.18.1",
        "@myorg/toggle-content-visibility": "^6.3.1",
        "@myorg/tooltip": "^14.0.0",
        "@myorg/typography": "^11.2.0",
        "@myorg/username-availability": "^1.0.3",
        "@myorg/visibility-sensor": "^7.0.1",
        "styled-components": "^5.3.6",
        "@myorg/form-field-email": "^10.2.1",
        "@myorg/data-layer": "^8.0.3",
        "@myorg/form-field-password": "^14.3.1",
        "@myorg/button": "^18.6.1",
        "@myorg/link": "^17.0.1",
        "react": "17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "17.0.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@myorg/test-utils": "^2.0.0",
        "@babel/cli": "^7.19.3",
        "@babel/core": "^7.20.2",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
        "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.18.6",
        "@babel/register": "^7.18.9",
        "@cerner/duplicate-package-checker-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.0",
        "@storybook/addon-a11y": "^6.4.19",
        "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.5.9",
        "@storybook/addon-knobs": "^6.4.0",
        "@storybook/addon-queryparams": "^6.2.9",
        "@storybook/addon-storyshots": "^6.5.9",
        "@storybook/addon-storyshots-puppeteer": "^6.5.9",
        "@storybook/addon-storysource": "^6.5.9",
        "@storybook/react": "^6.5.13",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
        "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.5",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
        "@types/classnames": "2.3.1",
        "@types/jest": "^29.2.3",
        "@types/jsdom": "16.2.14",
        "@types/node": "14.14.28",
        "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.23",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.18.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.18.0",
        "autoprefixer": "9.8.6",
        "babel-eslint-parser": "^7.13.10",
        "babel-jest": "^29.3.1",
        "babel-loader": "^8.3.0",
        "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "^2.3.3",
        "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.1.0",
        "babel-plugin-require-context-hook": "^1.0.0",
        "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
        "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
        "commitizen": "4.2.4",
        "cross-env": "7.0.3",
        "css-loader": "5.2.7",
        "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "1.0.0",
        "cz-conventional-changelog": "3.3.0",
        "enzyme": "3.11.0",
        "eslint": "^8.12.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.29.4",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.4.0",
        "eslint-plugin-unused-imports": "^2.0.0",
        "fetch-mock": "9.11.0",
        "fetch-mock-jest": "1.5.1",
        "file-loader": "6.2.0",
        "husky": "^7.0.0",
        "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
        "jest": "^29.3.1",
        "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.3.1",
        "jest-fetch-mock": "^3.0.3",
        "jest-junit": "^15.0.0",
        "jest-progress-bar-reporter": "^1.0.25",
        "less": "3.12.2",
        "less-loader": "7.2.1",
        "lint-staged": "12.4.1",
        "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.6.2",
        "mockdate": "3.0.5",
        "postcss-loader": "4.1.0",
        "preact": "10.8.2",
        "preact-render-to-json": "3.6.6",
        "prettier": "2.6.2",
        "puppeteer": "^13.1.3",
        "react": "17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "17.0.2",
        "sonarqube-scanner": "2.8.1",
        "standard-version": "9.3.2",
        "style-loader": "2.0.0",
        "ts-jest": "^29.0.3",
        "typescript": "4.6.4",
        "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0",
        "url-loader": "4.1.1",
        "webpack": "4.44.1",
        "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.5.0",
        "webpack-cli": "4.9.2"
    }
}
```

Oddly enough this module is use in the component where the test is failing on.

Answer (score 0):

In the end the TS validation was definitely not the issue. After replacing `ts-jest` by `babel-jest` in the  the `jest.config.ts` the actual error was shown. An missing Context Provider in the test setup.